# "Malformed patch" error while applying the diff to wget source with patch  

Tags: wget, patch

I would like to apply [this patch](http://osdir.com/ml/web.wget.patches/2007-07/msg00011.html) so I copied code beginning at "Index: src/options.h" and ending with "+@item" and put it into a new file created in `wget`'s source code folder. Then I did:

```
$ patch -p0 < name_of_patch
(Patch is indented 1 space.)
patching file src/options.h
patch: **** malformed patch at line 6: char **excludes; /* List of excluded FTP directories. */
```

How am I supposed to apply this?

This is the content of the file I created:

```
 Index: src/options.h
 ===================================================================
 --- src/options.h (revision 2276)
 +++ src/options.h (working copy)
 @@ -62,6 +62,8 @@
 char **excludes; /* List of excluded FTP directories. */
 char **includes; /* List of FTP directories to
 follow. */
 + int maxsize; /* Maximum file size (kB) */
 + int minsize; /* Minimum file size (kB) */
 bool ignore_case; /* Whether to ignore case when
 matching dirs and files */

 Index: src/init.c
 ===================================================================
 --- src/init.c (revision 2276)
 +++ src/init.c (working copy)
 @@ -182,6 +182,8 @@
 { "loadcookies", &opt.cookies_input, cmd_file },
 { "logfile", &opt.lfilename, cmd_file },
 { "login", &opt.ftp_user, cmd_string },/* deprecated*/
 + { "maxsize", &opt.maxsize, cmd_number },
 + { "minsize", &opt.minsize, cmd_number },
 { "mirror", NULL, cmd_spec_mirror },
 { "netrc", &opt.netrc, cmd_boolean },
 { "noclobber", &opt.noclobber, cmd_boolean },
 Index: src/http.c
 ===================================================================
 --- src/http.c (revision 2276)
 +++ src/http.c (working copy)
 @@ -2252,7 +2252,7 @@
 retried, and retried, and retried, and... */
 uerr_t
 http_loop (struct url *u, char **newloc, char **local_file, const char 
 *referer,
 - int *dt, struct url *proxy)
 + int *dt, struct url *proxy, bool can_ommit)
 {
 int count;
 bool got_head = false; /* used for time-stamping and filename 
 detection */
 @@ -2285,6 +2285,27 @@
 if (opt.ftp_glob && has_wildcards_p (u->path))
 logputs (LOG_VERBOSE, _("Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.\n"));

 + /* Try fetching the document header and checking the document length */
 + if (can_ommit && !opt.spider && !opt.ignore_length &&
 + (opt.minsize > 0 || opt.maxsize > 0))
 + {
 + /* Setup hstat struct. */
 + xzero (hstat);
 + hstat.referer = referer;
 +
 + *dt = HEAD_ONLY;
 + err = gethttp (u, &hstat, dt, proxy);
 + 
 + if (err == RETRFINISHED && hstat.contlen > 0 &&
 + (opt.minsize > 0 && hstat.contlen < opt.minsize * 1024 ||
 + opt.maxsize > 0 && hstat.contlen > opt.maxsize * 1024)) 
 + {
 + logputs (LOG_VERBOSE, _("File too small or too big -- not 
 retrieving.\n"));
 + ret = FILEBADFILE;
 + goto exit;
 + }
 + }
 +
 /* Setup hstat struct. */
 xzero (hstat);
 hstat.referer = referer;
 @@ -2300,7 +2321,7 @@

 /* Reset the document type. */
 *dt = 0;
 - 
 +
 /* THE loop */
 do
 {
 Index: src/http.h
 ===================================================================
 --- src/http.h (revision 2276)
 +++ src/http.h (working copy)
 @@ -32,7 +32,7 @@
 struct url;

 uerr_t http_loop (struct url *, char **, char **, const char *, int *,
 - struct url *);
 + struct url *, bool);
 void save_cookies (void);
 void http_cleanup (void);
 time_t http_atotm (const char *);
 Index: src/res.c
 ===================================================================
 --- src/res.c (revision 2276)
 +++ src/res.c (working copy)
 @@ -545,7 +545,7 @@
 *file = NULL;
 opt.timestamping = false;
 opt.spider = false;
 - err = retrieve_url (robots_url, file, NULL, NULL, NULL, false);
 + err = retrieve_url (robots_url, file, NULL, NULL, NULL, false, false);
 opt.timestamping = saved_ts_val;
 opt.spider = saved_sp_val; 
 xfree (robots_url);
 Index: src/retr.c
 ===================================================================
 --- src/retr.c (revision 2276)
 +++ src/retr.c (working copy)
 @@ -601,7 +601,7 @@

 uerr_t
 retrieve_url (const char *origurl, char **file, char **newloc,
 - const char *refurl, int *dt, bool recursive)
 + const char *refurl, int *dt, bool recursive, bool can_ommit)
 {
 uerr_t result;
 char *url;
 @@ -676,7 +676,7 @@
 #endif
 || (proxy_url && proxy_url->scheme == SCHEME_HTTP))
 {
 - result = http_loop (u, &mynewloc, &local_file, refurl, dt, proxy_url);
 + result = http_loop (u, &mynewloc, &local_file, refurl, dt, proxy_url, 
 can_ommit);
 }
 else if (u->scheme == SCHEME_FTP)
 {
 @@ -856,7 +856,7 @@
 opt.follow_ftp = old_follow_ftp;
 }
 else
 - status = retrieve_url (cur_url->url->url, &filename, &new_file, NULL, 
 &dt, opt.recursive);
 + status = retrieve_url (cur_url->url->url, &filename, &new_file, NULL, 
 &dt, opt.recursive, false);

 if (filename && opt.delete_after && file_exists_p (filename))
 {
 Index: src/retr.h
 ===================================================================
 --- src/retr.h (revision 2276)
 +++ src/retr.h (working copy)
 @@ -49,7 +49,7 @@
 char *fd_read_hunk (int, hunk_terminator_t, long, long);
 char *fd_read_line (int);

 -uerr_t retrieve_url (const char *, char **, char **, const char *, int *, 
 bool);
 +uerr_t retrieve_url (const char *, char **, char **, const char *, int *, 
 bool, bool);
 uerr_t retrieve_from_file (const char *, bool, int *);

 const char *retr_rate (wgint, double);
 Index: src/recur.c
 ===================================================================
 --- src/recur.c (revision 2276)
 +++ src/recur.c (working copy)
 @@ -247,7 +247,7 @@
 int dt = 0;
 char *redirected = NULL;

 - status = retrieve_url (url, &file, &redirected, referer, &dt, false);
 + status = retrieve_url (url, &file, &redirected, referer, &dt, false, 
 !html_allowed);

 if (html_allowed && file && status == RETROK
 && (dt & RETROKF) && (dt & TEXTHTML))
 Index: src/main.c
 ===================================================================
 --- src/main.c (revision 2276)
 +++ src/main.c (working copy)
 @@ -189,6 +189,8 @@
 { "level", 'l', OPT_VALUE, "reclevel", -1 },
 { "limit-rate", 0, OPT_VALUE, "limitrate", -1 },
 { "load-cookies", 0, OPT_VALUE, "loadcookies", -1 },
 + { "max-size", 'M', OPT_VALUE, "maxsize", -1 },
 + { "min-size", 's', OPT_VALUE, "minsize", -1 },
 { "mirror", 'm', OPT_BOOLEAN, "mirror", -1 },
 { "no", 'n', OPT__NO, NULL, required_argument },
 { "no-clobber", 0, OPT_BOOLEAN, "noclobber", -1 },
 @@ -446,6 +448,10 @@
 N_("\
 --limit-rate=RATE limit download rate to RATE.\n"),
 N_("\
 + -M, --max-size=SIZE limit maximum file size to SIZE (kB).\n"),
 + N_("\
 + -s, --min-size=SIZE limit minimum file size to SIZE (kB).\n"),
 + N_("\
 --no-dns-cache disable caching DNS lookups.\n"),
 N_("\
 --restrict-file-names=OS restrict chars in file names to ones OS 
 allows.\n"),
 @@ -675,7 +681,6 @@
 stdout);
 exit (0);
 }
 - 
 #ifndef TESTING
 int
 main (int argc, char *const *argv)
 @@ -979,7 +984,7 @@
 opt.follow_ftp = old_follow_ftp;
 }
 else
 - status = retrieve_url (*t, &filename, &redirected_URL, NULL, &dt, 
 opt.recursive);
 + status = retrieve_url (*t, &filename, &redirected_URL, NULL, &dt, 
 opt.recursive, false);

 if (opt.delete_after && file_exists_p(filename))
 {
 Index: doc/wget.texi
 ===================================================================
 --- doc/wget.texi (revision 2276)
 +++ doc/wget.texi (working copy)
 @@ -1592,7 +1592,7 @@
 @item -l @var{depth}
 @itemx --level=@var{depth}
 Specify recursion maximum depth level @var{depth} (@pxref{Recursive
 -Download}). The default maximum depth is 5.
 +Download}). The default maximum depth is 5. Zero means infinite recursion.

 @cindex proxy filling
 @cindex delete after retrieval
 @@ -1803,6 +1803,15 @@
 Specify the domains that are @emph{not} to be followed.
 (@pxref{Spanning Hosts}).

 +@cindex file size range
 +@item -s @var{size}
 +@itemx --min-size=@var{size}
 +Limit the minimum size of non-HTML files to @var{size} kB. Smaller files will 
 not be retrieved.
 +
 +@item -M @var{size}
 +@itemx --max-size=@var{size}
 +Limit the maximum size of non-HTML files to @var{size} kB. Larger files will 
 not be retrieved.
 +
 @cindex follow FTP links
 @item --follow-ftp
 Follow @sc{ftp} links from @sc{html} documents. Without this option,
 @@ -3064,6 +3073,14 @@
 too.

 @item
 +Retrieve in directory 'pics' all jpeg images from a given site, excluding
 +files smaller than 50k (to avoid thumbnails) or larger than 400k.
 +
 +@example
 +wget -Ppics -nd -r -l0 -Ajpg,jpeg -s50 -M400 http://www.server.com
 +@end example
 +
 +@item
 Suppose you were in the middle of downloading, when Wget was
 interrupted. Now you do not want to clobber the files already present.
 It would be:
 Index: src/utils.c
 ===================================================================
 --- src/utils.c (revision 2276)
 +++ src/utils.c (working copy)
 @@ -432,33 +432,52 @@
 #endif
 }

 -/* stat file names named PREFIX.1, PREFIX.2, etc., until one that
 - doesn't exist is found. Return a freshly allocated copy of the
 - unused file name. */
 +/*
 + * Stat file names named PREFIX-1.SUFFIX, PREFIX-2.SUFFIX, etc., until
 + * one that doesn't exist is found. Return a freshly allocated copy of
 + * the unused file name.
 + */

 static char *
 -unique_name_1 (const char *prefix)
 +unique_name_1 (const char *s)
 {
 int count = 1;
 - int plen = strlen (prefix);
 - char *template = (char *)alloca (plen + 1 + 24);
 - char *template_tail = template + plen;
 + int p, l = strlen (s);
 + char *prefix = (char *) alloca (l + 1);
 + char *suffix = (char *) alloca (l + 1);
 + char *filename = (char *) alloca (l + 26);
 + 
 + /* Look for last '.' in filename */
 + 
 + for(p = l; p >= 0 && s[p] != '.'; p--);

 - memcpy (template, prefix, plen);
 - *template_tail++ = '.';
 + /* If none found, then prefix is the whole filename */
 + 
 + if (p < 0)
 + p = l;

 + /* Extract prefix and (possibly empty) suffix from filename */
 + 
 + memcpy (prefix, s, p);
 + prefix[p] = '\0';
 +
 + memcpy (suffix, s+p, l-p);
 + suffix[l-p] = '\0';
 +
 + /* Try indexed filenames until an unused one is found */
 + 
 do
 - number_to_string (template_tail, count++);
 - while (file_exists_p (template));
 + sprintf (filename, "%s-%d%s", prefix, count++, suffix);
 + while (file_exists_p (filename));

 - return xstrdup (template);
 + return xstrdup (filename);
 }

 /* Return a unique file name, based on FILE.

 - More precisely, if FILE doesn't exist, it is returned unmodified.
 - If not, FILE.1 is tried, then FILE.2, etc. The first FILE.<number>
 - file name that doesn't exist is returned.
 + More precisely, if FILE.SUF doesn't exist, it is returned unmodified.
 + If not, FILE-1.SUF is tried, then FILE-2.SUF etc. The first
 + FILE-<number>.SUF file name that doesn't exist is returned.

 The resulting file is not created, only verified that it didn't
 exist at the point in time when the function was called.
 Index: doc/wget.texi
 ===================================================================
 --- doc/wget.texi (revision 2276)
 +++ doc/wget.texi (working copy)
 @@ -561,16 +561,16 @@
 cases, the local file will be @dfn{clobbered}, or overwritten, upon
 repeated download. In other cases it will be preserved.

 -When running Wget without @samp{-N}, @samp{-nc}, or @samp{-r},
 -downloading the same file in the same directory will result in the
 -original copy of @var{file} being preserved and the second copy being
 -named @samp{@var{file}.1}. If that file is downloaded yet again, the
 -third copy will be named @samp{@var{file}.2}, and so on. When
 -@samp{-nc} is specified, this behavior is suppressed, and Wget will
 -refuse to download newer copies of @samp{@var{file}}. Therefore,
 -``@code{no-clobber}'' is actually a misnomer in this mode---it's not
 -clobbering that's prevented (as the numeric suffixes were already
 -preventing clobbering), but rather the multiple version saving that's
 +When running Wget without @samp{-N}, @samp{-nc}, or @samp{-r}, downloading the
 +same file in the same directory will result in the original copy of @var{file}
 +being preserved and the second copy being named
 +@samp{@var{prefix}-1.@var{suffix}}, assuming @var{file} = @var{prefix.suffix}.
 +If that file is downloaded yet again, the third copy will be named
 +@samp{@var{prefix}-2.@var{suffix}}, and so on. When @samp{-nc} is specified,
 +this behavior is suppressed, and Wget will refuse to download newer copies of
 +@samp{@var{file}}. Therefore, ``@code{no-clobber}'' is actually a misnomer in
 +this mode---it's not clobbering that's prevented (as the numeric suffixes were
 +already preventing clobbering), but rather the multiple version saving that's
 prevented.

 When running Wget with @samp{-r}, but without @samp{-N} or @samp{-nc},
 @@ -1592,7 +1592,7 @@
 @item -l @var{depth}
 @itemx --level=@var{depth}
 Specify recursion maximum depth level @var{depth} (@pxref{Recursive
 -Download}). The default maximum depth is 5.
 +Download}). The default maximum depth is 5. Zero means infinite recursion.

 @cindex proxy filling
 @cindex delete after retrieval
 @@ -1803,6 +1803,15 @@
 Specify the domains that are @emph{not} to be followed.
 (@pxref{Spanning Hosts}).

 +@cindex file size range
 +@item -s @var{size}
 +@itemx --min-size=@var{size}
 +Limit the minimum size of non-HTML files to @var{size} kB. Smaller files will 
 not be retrieved.
 +
 +@item -M @var{size}
 +@itemx --max-size=@var{size}
 +Limit the maximum size of non-HTML files to @var{size} kB. Larger files will 
 not be retrieved.
 +
 @cindex follow FTP links
 @item --follow-ftp
 Follow @sc{ftp} links from @sc{html} documents. Without this option,
 @@ -3064,6 +3073,14 @@
 too.

 @item
 +Retrieve in directory 'pics' all jpeg images from a given site, excluding
 +files smaller than 50k (to avoid thumbnails) or larger than 400k.
 +
 +@example
 +wget -Ppics -nd -r -l0 -Ajpg,jpeg -s50 -M400 http://www.server.com
 +@end example
 +
 +@item
```

Comment: Paste what you actually copied, please.

Comment: ok,edited original post

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a common problem with diffs copied/pasted into a text file without space indentation. You need to add space in front of each line, except for lines beginning with the symbols "+", "-" and "@@".  To avoid this problem, it is better to generate the diff files yourself by hand (using `diff` or a version control diff tool) and then download the diff file as whole, instead of copying and pasting from your browser.

I would suggest that before applying the patch, you check if the patch has made it upstream, and is available in newer/latest/stable release, which would solve your problem in a clean way. Even if you patch the `.c` file, you are going to compile it anyway, so why not do it with a fresh stable tarball, if the patch has made into upstream.

Answer (score 3):

I second Nikhils general comments. However, I'll just point out that you are in general better off downloading the html file and then converting it to text, rather than using cut and paste. For example, you can do

1) wget -c http://osdir.com/ml/web.wget.patches/2007-07/msg00011.html

2) Open msg00011.html with Openoffice, for example. and save as text. The OO converter does a good job, and I didn't see any obvious problems with the converted patches.